# OneDrive selective sync top level files

Tags: sync, cloud, microsoft

Is there a way to setup selective OneDrive sync to include files at the root of my OneDrive? My `sync_list` file looks like this (but root files are not copied down):

```
FolderA
FolderB
FolderC
```

I've tried an additional entree for `*`, `*.*`, and `.*` but none work.

I'm using OneDrive (apt install onedrive) v1.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, the `onedrive` apt package seems wildly out of date. Last update from September of 2017.

I've personally been using [this one by abraunegg](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive).

It's been working pretty well and lets you configure the folders and files not to be loaded in the `~/.config/onedrive/config`-File.

By default it will load all the files in your onedrive folder.